# module not find in node.js

Tags: node.js, module

i try to run a simple node.js code withg tutorial but it keep throw this err i update my node but didnt work

try to update node and reinstall the lodash

```
const custonEmitter = require("events")

const custonEmitter = new EventEmitter()

custonEmitter.on("massage",()=>{
    console.log(`data:`)
})
custonEmitter.emit("massage")
```

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\pari\Desktop\node.js\app'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to just run `app` and that file doesn't exist? Most likely it'll be `app.js` or `app.mjs`. Also, I didn't know Stack Overflow supported _spoilers_ (I removed them). To help you further, please add the commands you are running so we can see what you are doing that's causing this error. This is not about the internal module not being found, it's about the entry module not being found I think.

Comment: Can you share the file structure of the project and the command line you use to try and run it?